# Backup YUMI Multiboot Kali Live USB

Tags: linux, backup, multi-boot, kali-linux, liveusb

I have a 128GB USB with YUMI Multiboot. I have a few Linux distro including Ubuntu and Mint. I also have AVG and Comodo and a few others. Most importantly, I have a Kali Linux Live USB with persistence. The persistence drive is separate around 80+GB. Mint has Casper-rw. Everything works fine. I have a question. I added a lot to the Kali Live with its persistence drive. I would like to backup just Kali. (Not the other Linux distros.) So how do I do that with Multiboot? I don't want the other distros (sdb) just Kali and sdb2 (persistence.) I read about the "dd" command on Linux. And "cat". But I can't back up just the Kali Live USB. "sdb" has all the multiboot Linux and tools. Not just Kali. And "dd" creates and ISO. Would it be 80+GB? That sounds wrong. I'd like to backup to an external HD 160GB. It has around 100GB free. It's NTFS and I don't think Kali can see it. Also, should I do this from inside the Kali Live or from my normal Windows 10? So how do I backup my Kali Live USB with its persistence drive? Please reply. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

this question is in a way too ... simple? ... for this forum, and deviates from your other skills ... (kali, persistence, multiboot, ...)

besides that it's a quite special question, for a reliable answer one needs to have a very similar setup,

1. from / under which system do you want to make the backup, running kali? would be ok,
2. what sort of backup do you want, one-time? repeated? gandfather - father - son? evertime full? full with incrementals? full with differentials? raw-disk-data or file by file, you need a strategy,
3. you need some space where to put the backup, accessible by the system making the backup and!!! accessible in some way if your standard system fails, imho kali can mount ntfs, but will have problems storing appropriate file system permissions, thus a fs similar to the source is preferable, if you follow my thoughts twice the amount of source data is fine, preferably don't use the backup media for any other purpose,
4. find the data to back up, the kali live file wouldn't change, but note which you used, the yumi setup you can get from web, todo is 'persistence' and notes for the setup, as you already know persistence is on sdb2 you should be able to: - either find where it's mounted into the dir-tree, imho twice!, or - mount it yourself in an app. place, 'mount | grep sdb*' can be a friend,
5. i'd recommend rsync and a script near to 'Mike Rubels', see: http://www.mikerubel.org/computers/rsync_snapshots/
6. that's a good plan to do easy, quick, powerful! backups, and to do them often!, very fast and space saving for small files with some of them added or changed, also working well but with less advantages for big files with small changes every day (e.g. a 'maildir' account with 2GB of old data in old files and some small new files will backup in seconds by 'hardlinking' the old files, while a 'mbox' file which adds the new mails to one monster file which is changed and 'to archive' from that point on will take much more space and time),
7. reg. dd: nice tool if you want 1:1 copies of whole disks or partitions, careful, very sharp knife, writes absolutely what you defined without any check or warning, even every fault or crap!, triple-check before firing! wastes space backing devices not being full, but if a was you i'd make one copy of the actual stick and put it aside additional! to making regular backups,
8. i hope your persistence is encrypted? if not - do it after saving a backup, sticks get lost sometimes :-(
9. reg. experimenting with configs and getting kali un-bootable: i have quite good experience to access the persistence from another system, rename the folders there to something else (e.g. *_sav or *_def), boot kali 'as new', and put the info from the old folders back piece by piece ...
10. using sticks as targets: keep in mind that most of them are fast for small amounts of data, and much! slower for big data because they protect themself against heat-damage by 'thermal-throtteling', e.g. sandisk ultra-fit faster than 100 MB/sec for about 2 GB, but less than 20 MB/sec on the long run, fastest i know at the moment sandisk extreme pro (not! 'extreme go'), but very sensitive to mechanical kinking, use a short cable to attach them,
11. absolute must! everybody should know but nearly nobody cares for: a backup isn't a backup unless you:
    a) did a compare run,
    b) tested to be able to rebuild the whole system 'from scratch and backup',
    consider either a complete fail or a complete theft, you need notes on everything. just had a case, mb with special bios with special settings for disk access, lost bios setup info, no chance to reconstruct disk setup, data is accessible, system recovery will take full raw data backup, and hours of trial and error ...

reg.

b.